# vba excel copy subtable from sheet to sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I realize that this is probably a duplicate, but I've been searching for an hour and I can't to get the syntax right.
I have a sheet with several tables. There is at least one empty column and one empty row between one table to the other.

I know the start row and start column of each table, and I know that each table has 3 columns. I don't know how many rows it has.

I want to write a sub that receives:

1. table start row
2. table start column

and copies the table into another sheet (let's say that the destination is sheet2 starting at A1).

I know I can do it with a loop, but I suspect there is a better syntax right?
(The main issue here is that I need to find the number of rows each table has)

Thanks.
Li

Comment: The solution below is correct (+1), but if your tables are bounded by empty rows and columns the `CurrentRegion` property might be simpler :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx. You can probably do a one-liner: `Cells(lRow,lColumn).CurrentRegion.Copy Target`.

Comment: @loannis: this is perfect! one liner...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sub will do the job:

```
Sub CopyTable(wsSource As Worksheet, lngTopRow As Long, intLeftCol As Integer, rngTarget As Range)
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim intCols As Integer, lngRows As Long

    Set rngSource = wsSource.Cells(lngTopRow, intLeftCol)
    intCols = rngSource.End(xlToRight).Column - intLeftCol + 1
    lngRows = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, intLeftCol).End(xlUp).Row - lngTopRow + 1

    rngSource.Resize(lngRows, intCols).Copy rngTarget

End Sub
```

To copy a table starting in rows 1, column 5 of worksheet1 to Sheet2!A2, use the following call:

```
CopyTable Sheets("Sheet1"), 1, 5, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
```

This assumes that there's nothing below each table. If that is not the case, replace the 3rd instruction with

```
lngRows = rngSource.End(xlDown).Row - lngTopRow + 1
```

This will now assume, that the first column of your table has no gaps. If this is not true, try using `rngSource.UsedRange.Row` instead of `rngSource.End(xlDown).Row`!